# What is intramolecular energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I got this term while reading a portion of specific heat capacity in Ideal gas chapter. What does it mean? Does it mean internal energy?

Comment: yes I think that it must do. Inter-molecular is between molecules, intra- within a molecule. It is usually used in the context of intra-molecular energy transfer, such as occurs after absorbing energy from a photon.